# select specified number of unique IDs where second column is unique

Tags: postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Look at the following example starting from the top row (`id=9`) and work your way down, selecting a **limit** of `4` rows that have `sec`'s that we have not yet seen. We "select" `id=9` because we don't yet have `sec=1`. We continue to work our way down like this, but when we get to `id=7` we skip it because we already have `sec=5` (from row with `id=8`). We continue in the same manner, and we finally stop at `id=3` because we have accumulated `4` rows (our desired limit).

```
 id | sec
----+-----
  9 |   1  <- 1
  8 |   5  <- 2
  7 |   5  # skip, already have sec=5
  6 |   4  <- 3
  5 |   1  # skip, already have sec=1
  4 |   1  # skip, already have sec=1
  3 |   3  <- 4
  2 |   2
  1 |   1
```

Of course the `SQL` algorithm can (will!) be different than I described.

Desired result:

```
 id
----
  9
  8
  6
  3
(4 rows)
```

If I wanted to increase the limit to `5` rows, then the row with `id=2` *would* be included in the results. However, if I increased the limit to `6` rows, the row with `id=1` would *not* be added because `sec=1` has already been seen.

Note: Though it shouldn't matter, I am on **PostgreSQL 9.3.1**.

---

In case you want to quickly build the table to test this out:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id serial primary key, sec integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO my_table (sec) VALUES
  (1)
, (2)
, (3)
, (1)
, (1)
, (4)
, (5)
, (5)
, (1);
CREATE INDEX index_my_table_on_sec ON my_table (sec);
```

Comment: I had a new idea and added a working recursive CTE to my answer (finally). Would you mind comparing performance on your big table?

Comment: Sure, but please tell me how to use it - just as earlier you showed me how to call your `f_first_uniq` function.

Comment: Oh, it's just a plain query. Use it just like the other query. I added a demo to the fiddle (which seems to be down atm).

Comment: On my computer, given a table of `1M` rows, on average the `PARTITION` query takes `5.9s`, the `DISTINCT` query takes `3.6s`, the `RECURSIVE` query takes `1.5s`, and the `FUNCTION` query takes less than `1ms`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It's good to back the quick tests with some "real life" numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Postgres, this is simpler with `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (sec)
          id, sec
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY sec, id DESC
   ) sub
ORDER  BY id DESC
LIMIT  4;
```

Detailed explanation in this related answer on SO:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

For a **big table** and **small `LIMIT`**, neither this nor [@a_horse's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62601/3684) are very efficient. The subquery will plough through the whole table, wasting a lot of time ...

#### Recursive CTE

I have tried and failed to solve similar problems with a recursive CTE in the past and resorted to a procedural solution with PL/pgSQL. Example:

- [Self-join unique pairs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61173/self-join-unique-pairs/61237#61237)

Finally, here is a working rCTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (  -- parentheses required
   SELECT id, '{}'::int[] AS last_arr, ARRAY[sec] AS arr
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT b.id, c.arr
        , CASE WHEN b.sec = ANY (c.arr) THEN c.arr ELSE b.sec  || c.arr END
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN   tbl b ON b.id < c.id
   WHERE  array_length(c.arr, 1) < 4
   ORDER  BY id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   )
SELECT id, arr[1] AS sec
FROM   cte
WHERE  last_arr <> arr;
```

It's not as fast or elegant as I had hoped for and not nearly as fast as the function below, but faster than the query above in my tests.

#### PL/pgSQL function

***Fastest*** by far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_first_uniq(_rows int)
   RETURNS TABLE (id int, sec int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _arr int[];
BEGIN
   FOR id, sec IN
      SELECT t.id, t.sec FROM tbl t ORDER BY t.id DESC
   LOOP
      IF sec = ANY (_arr) THEN
         -- do nothing
      ELSE
         RETURN NEXT;
         _arr := _arr || sec;
         EXIT WHEN array_length(_arr, 1) >= _rows;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_first_uniq(4);
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/06db6/27)** demonstrating all three.

Could be made out to work for any table with table and column names as parameters and dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` ...

#### Why bother?

In a test table with only `30k` rows the function ran **2000x** faster than the above query (which already ran ~ 30% faster than a_horse's version). This difference grows with the size of the table. Performance of the function is about constant, while the query's performance gets progressively worse, since it tries to find distinct values in *all* of the table first. Try this in a table with a million rows ...

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT id,
       sec
FROM (
  SELECT id,
         sec,
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sec ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
  FROM my_table
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 4;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1ca01/1

Comment: I know we're supposed to avoid "thanks" comments, but I really want to let you know how much I appreciate this answer - it does exactly what I need, and I would not have been able to come up with it myself. So, *thank you kindly!* Out of curiosity, and as far as you know, is there more than one way to do it or is this pretty much it?

Comment: @user664833: Feedback like this (including thanks) in a *comment* is welcome. Just keep the noise level in questions and answers low.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Ok. Do you think my question had too much noise, and if so, what could have been avoided or improved? Thanks!

Comment: @user664833: Your question is good. You might have started with *what* you want instead of a detailed algorithm *how* to get it. And I'll trim some noise from your code. But you made your case clear and your question is good.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name: I am very sorry, and with all due respect, I had to re-assign the *answer* mark to @ErwinBrandstetter because his `DISTINCT ON` solution is considerably faster than yours (`28-43%`) based on my benchmarks on a table with `100k` rows (his query regularly returns in `450-500ms`. Furthermore, the speed of his `f_first_uniq` function is remarkable (it regularly returns in `0.5-5ms`. Nonetheless, I do sincerely appreciate your answer, and would have continued to use your solution had @ErwinBrandstetter not presented his. I thank you kindly once again.

Comment: @user664833: don't be sorry, that is absolutely OK.