# How to count last records from table where cell null before same cell is not null by order

Tags: postgresql

I have simple table with conversation.

```
  id   | room_id | member_id |       message        |          readtime          
-------+---------+-----------+----------------------+----------------------------
 81531 |    7992 |         1 | S:TestMessage        | 2018-07-21 17:27:39.844148
 81533 |    7992 |        16 | R:TestOK             | 2018-07-21 17:27:55.914063
 81545 |    7992 |        16 | R:hi                 | 
 81546 |    7992 |        16 | R:hi2                | 
 81547 |    7992 |        16 | R:ho1                | 
 81548 |    7992 |        16 | R:1111               | 2018-07-22 19:14:14.926177
 81550 |    7992 |        16 | R:33                 | 
 81551 |    7992 |        16 | R:33abc              | 
(8 rows)
```

As we can see, last 2 messages has not been read.
For other cases, possible several last messages was not read or all messages has been read.

I have only `room_id` to filter messages.

My query is

```
SELECT id, room_id, member_id, message, readtime FROM dialog_message WHERE room_id = 7992
```

I see three conditions:

1. Last record must have readtime is null
2. Count from end while readtime is null
3. member_id like in last records

So, how can select only last unread messages, represented before id 81548?

I mean id 81550 and 81551.

81548 - has been read and above 81547-81545 read too, even `readtime` is null

PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: show the desired results.

Comment: Do you need a *count* or the *set of rows with all columns* as result? Remember to disclose your Postgres version and table definition (`CREATE TABLE statement showing data types and constraints) for questions like this.

Comment: You accepted my answer, but I suspect you are looking for something different: Can there be multiple threads with dangling NULL rows for different `member_id` in the same `room_id`? (Indicated by your remark: *member_id like in last records*) Then the matter is more sophisticated. To make my point clear: consider this alternative fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=728010eef13c6f3fa50ebc6d910eee7d  Is ***that*** what you are really looking for?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly. Am I guessing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Assuming:***

- you need the set of rows with all columns like your query attempt suggests, not the *count* of rows like your title suggests.
- "last messages", "before" etc. are defined by the `id` column in your example.
  <sub>**Careful:** [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) ID numbers are not reliably continuous quantities. Rows inserted "later" may have a lower ID under rare circumstances.</sub>
- there can be multiple threads with trailing NULL rows for multiple different `member_id` in the same `room_id`.

You'll need a **multicolumn index** like this one in *any* case:

```
CREATE INDEX ON dialog_message(room_id, member_id, id DESC);
```

#### With a `NOT EXISTS` semi-join

For **small tables** or cases with only few stale rows with `readtime IS NULL` but a later row with `readtime IS NOT NULL` excluding those, I'd try a partial multicolumn index

You need this index *in addition* to the one above for best read performance:

```
CREATE INDEX ON dialog_message(room_id) WHERE readtime IS NULL;
```

Query:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM   dialog_message d
WHERE  d.room_id = 7992
AND    d.readtime IS NULL
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM dialog_message
   WHERE  room_id   = d.room_id
   AND    member_id = d.member_id
   AND    readtime IS NOT NULL
   AND    id > d.id
   );
```

#### Double recursive CTE

For big tables or cases with lots of stale rows with `readtime IS NULL`, I'd expect a **recursive CTE** to be fastest among pure SQL solutions:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (  -- get latest row for each member_id
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   dialog_message
   WHERE  room_id = 7992
   ORDER  BY member_id, id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT d.*
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   dialog_message d USING (room_id)
   WHERE  d.member_id > cte.member_id
   ORDER  BY d.member_id, id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   )
, cte2 AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  readtime IS NULL  -- IF not null, look for more ...

   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT d.*
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   dialog_message d USING (room_id, member_id)
   WHERE  d.id < cte.id
   AND    cte.readtime IS NULL
   ORDER  BY d.id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte2
WHERE  readtime IS NULL;  -- trim the bounding row with readtime IS NOT NULL
```

#### Recursive CTE combined with PL/pgSQL function

Might be one of the rare cases where a **procedural solution with a PL/pgSQL function** is even faster because it can make do with ***a single index scan*** per call.

Create this function ***once***:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_latest_unread_messages(_room_id int, _member_id int)
   RETURNS SETOF dialog_message AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _rec dialog_message;
BEGIN
   FOR _rec IN
      SELECT *
      FROM   dialog_message d
      WHERE  d.room_id   = _room_id
      AND    d.member_id = _member_id
      ORDER  BY d.id DESC
   LOOP
      IF _rec.readtime IS NULL THEN
         RETURN NEXT _rec;
      ELSE
         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Combine the outer rCTE from above with the function:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM   dialog_message
   WHERE  room_id = 7992
   ORDER  BY member_id, id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT d.*
   FROM   cte
   JOIN   dialog_message d USING (room_id)
   WHERE  d.member_id > cte.member_id
   ORDER  BY d.member_id, id DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   )
SELECT m.*
FROM   cte c, f_latest_unread_messages(c.room_id, c.member_id) m
WHERE  c.readtime IS NULL;  -- trim rows with readtime NOT NULL immediately
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=82288a0e5d70b4c08be33c5c5583cc57)*

Related:

- [select specified number of unique IDs where second column is unique](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62598/select-specified-number-of-unique-ids-where-second-column-is-unique/62616#62616)
- [Grouping or Window](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window/166397#166397)

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement can be described as: Retrieve every message for a given room where `readtime IS NULL` and no other, later message for the same room exists, that has a `readtime`, that `IS NOT NULL` or is from another user.

Assuming `id` defines an order on the messages, that leads to a query like the following.

```
SELECT dm1.id,
       dm1.room_id,
       dm1.member_id,
       dm1.message,
       dm1.readtime
       FROM dialog_message dm1
       WHERE dm1.room_id = 7992
             AND dm1.readtime IS NULL
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM dialog_message dm2
                                    WHERE dm2.room_id = dm1.room_id
                                          AND dm2.id > dm1.id
                                          AND (dm2.readtime IS NOT NULL
                                                OR dm2.member_id <> dm1.member_id));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=cc01cd19584cd02c40bffbe190ae50e3)

Answer (score 0):

**Your input** as [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=aee95a4fe2d50212b05a5bb8ac5bc339), supposed **id** is **serial**

**Desired output**: 81550, 81551

In the same *room_id = 7992* and *order by readtime*, querying *ids* which has value **greater than** the *last id* which has *read-time is not null*.

```
 SELECT id, room_id, member_id, message, readtime
  FROM dialog_message
  WHERE id > ( 
    SELECT id FROM dialog_message WHERE room_id = 7992 AND readtime is not null ORDER BY readtime desc LIMIT 1
    ) AND room_id = 7992;
```

@Dmitry: Please let's me know if it's not correct your requirement.